# Installing Vulkan SDK without admin privilegs?

Tags: c++, windows, vulkan

I try to install [the official Vulkan SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#windows) on Windows 10. Unfortunately, the installer asks for admin privileges which I obviously do not have.

Nevertheless: Why at all? Is the SDK not just a bunch of header files mixed up with libraries and some hot samples?

I am looking for a way to get started with Vulkan using MinGW. Is there a .zip file I could use? Some kind of precompilation? Or am I at least able to compile Vulkan myself?

Comment: "*asks for admin privilegs which I obviusly do not have*" Um... why not? It's your computer, is it not? How do you install the graphics drivers that provide the Vulkan implementation if you lack admin privileges? "*Is the SDK not just a bunch of header files mixed up with libraries and some hot samples?*" No, it isn't.

Comment: "A bunch of header files and libraries" still needs a user-wide location to install.

Comment: Why user-wide? Maybe I am the only user running Vulkan applications of my device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the SDK at all. If you want to develop with Vulkan, all you need is a Vulkan-capable GPU with a recent driver and the [Vulkan headers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers).

Along with the headers you also need some way to load the actual Vulkan functions. If you don't want to do that manually, either build and link the [official loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader) or use a dynamic loader like [volk](https://github.com/zeux/volk).

The reason the SDK needs admin rights is because it's also installing the validation layers through the registry, but there's also the option to [compile them yourself](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers) and just tell the loader where to get them using an environment var called `VK_LAYER_PATH` instead of having to add registry keys for each of the layers.

Comment: Jeah, I got the headers working. However, the libraries to link with are missing. I get several undefined references ...

Comment: Yeah, you're missing out on the loader provided by the SDK. Either built yourself from [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader), or use a dynamic loader like [volk](https://github.com/zeux/volk).